# Using the KafkaAvroDeserializer with Alpakka

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kafka-consumer-api, avro, alpakka

I have a SchemaRegistry and a KafkaBroker from which I pull data with Avro v1.8.1. For deserialization I've been using Confluent's [KafkaAvroDeserializer](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroDeserializer.java). Now I've meant to refactor my code in order to use the [Elasticsearch API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/elasticsearch.html) provided by Alpakka, but unfortunately this breaks the deserialization, as it results in NullPointerExceptions:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition topic-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 2
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:116)
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:88)
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:58)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1030)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3300(Fetcher.java:110)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1250)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:545)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:506)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1269)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1200)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1176)
>       at de.adesso.fds.connectors.dpa.news.NewsConsumer.main(MyConsumer.java:58)

I've been using the ConsumerSettings API by Alpakka as described in this [example](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v1.0.2/doc-examples/src/main/java/elastic/KafkaToElasticInJava.java):

```
val system = ActorSystem.create();

// necessary to convert timestamps correctly in Avro Version 1.8.1 to avoid ClassCastExceptions
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());

val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings.create(system, new StringDeserializer(), new KafkaAvroDeserializer())
    .withBootstrapServers(kafkaBootstrapServerUrl)
    .withClientId(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
    .withGroupId("" + new Random().nextInt())
    .withProperty(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl)
    .withProperty(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true")
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    .withStopTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

These settings result in the NullPointerExceptions, while this vanilla Kafka Consumer props work fine:

```
val props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()); 
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "" + new Random().nextInt());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServerUrl);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
// necessary to convert timestamps correctly in newer Avro Versions and to avoid ClassCastExceptions
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, MyClass>(props);
```

In the working example, the values of the ConsumerRecords are successfully deserialized into the classes generated by the AvroMavenPlugin from a schema.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pull `new KafkaAvroDeserializer()` to its own variable, then call the `.configure()` method on that instance to pass in a non-null Registry URL.

Then pass in the configured instance to `ConsumerSettings.create`

FWIW, depending on your needs, Kafka Connect works fine to load Elasticsearch

Comment: Seems you're right: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/serialization.html

Comment: The reason I would prefer Alpakka to Kafka Connect is simply to avoid having to use confluent hub

Comment: My bad, didn't know confluent had a maven repo (why they don't publish on central is a mystery): https://packages.confluent.io/maven/

Comment: Because they have internal private packages that get pushed to the same repo that they have full control over. Google also maintains a separate Maven repo for Android development... Yet I've not seen so many people complain about that

Comment: And you don't need to use Confluent Hub. Running Connect Docker images from Confluent is one solution, and Elasticsearch connector is already included in it... Besides, I personally find Confluent Hub more straightforward than manually adding Kafka Connectors